# Expire Document with Tire Gem using ttl

Tags: elasticsearch, tire

I found the `_ttl` mapping in Elasticsearch. I wonder how can I use this mapping with `tire` gem. Code snippets are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not using the ActiveModel Integration, use @Marcus Granström answer

```
Tire.index 'index-with-ttl' do
  delete
  create mappings: {
  document: {
    _ttl:       { enabled: true , default: "1d" },     
    properties: {
      # properties goes here
    }
  }
}
refresh
end
```

If you're using ActiveModel Integration

```
tire do
    settings do
      # Expiring the index after 30 days (_ttl parameter) 
      # http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/ttl-field/
      mapping _ttl: { enabled: true, default: '30d' } do
        # add the indexes here
      end
    end    
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

No Tire expert at all but think this will do the trick:

```
Tire.index 'index-with-ttl' do
  delete
  create mappings: {
  document: {
    _ttl:       { enabled: true , default: "1d" },     
    properties: {
      # properties goes here
    }
  }
}
refresh
end
```